# Determining 'active' changeset with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

If you have changesets A, B, C, D, E in your repo and you execute `hg update -c D`, how can you confirm that your repo is currently 'active' with changeset D?   If we run `hg tip` or `hg head`, HG lists E and not D.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to find this out:

- [`hg summary`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/summary)
- [`hg identify`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/identify)
- [`hg log -r .`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log)

Note that [`hg update`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/update) actually changes the revision of your working copy, so you definitely should not use that.

Comment: Probably `hg parent` without arguments fits the best: "show the parents of the working directory". Four commands for such a simple action, that's what we usually criticize Git for. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I actually meant `hg head` as opposed to `hg update`.  I updated the question.